# my browsers won't allow live streaming and video calling or audio calling even after enabling webrtc on all browsers

Tags: webrtc, agora.io

i am working a social network platform and wanted to integrate the live streaming services and also the chat voice and audio calling services. they are all active, except that I keep getting "Sorry your browser does not have webrtc" even after installing this extension on all my browsers, it still says the same for Chrome, Firefox, and Microsoft Edge. The only browser working perfectly well is the apple safari browser. Now I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC has to work under https environment. That's why your website isn't working. Deploy the application with SSL security.